# Round number to nearest "nth" based on first non zero

Tags: ios, swift, double, rounding

I want to round a Double to the nearest non zero number that follows the decimal.

For example:

```
x = 0.002341
rounded = 0.002

x = 0.000048123
rounded = 0.00005
```

For cases where the base number is > 0, it should perform as such

```
x = 1.000234
rounded = 1.0002
```

I know I can use `Double(round(1000*x)/1000)` if I know the number of digits, but I want it to work for any number. Is there a swift function that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a little fun with logarithms to solve this:

```
func roundFirst(x:Double) -> Double {
    if x == 0 {
        return x;
    }
    let mul : Double = pow(10, floor(log10(abs(x))))
    return round(x/mul)*mul
}
```

The non-fractional part of `log10(abs(x))` gives you a positive or negative power of ten of the inverse of the number which you use as your multiplier. `floor` drops the fraction, and `pow(10,...)` gives you a multiplier to use in your rounding trick.

I tried this in the playground with a few numbers. Here is what I've got:

```
println(roundFirst(0.002341))     // 0.002
println(roundFirst(0.000048123))  // 5e-05
println(roundFirst(0.0))          // 0.0
println(roundFirst(2.6))          // 3.0
println(roundFirst(123.0))        // 100
println(roundFirst(-0.002341))    // -0.002
println(roundFirst(-0.000048123)) // -5e-05
println(roundFirst(-2.6))         // -3.0
println(roundFirst(-123.0))       // -100
```

Comment: Great solution, but doesn't work numbers > 0 with trailing decimals, for example: `roundFirst(2.0234)` returns 2

Comment: @mattymcgee That's exactly how I understood your problem - I thought that you wanted to keep the highest-value digit, which in case of `2.0234` is `2`. If you would like to apply this solution only to the fractional part, use `modf` to separate the whole and the fractional, use `roundFirst`, and re-combine the two parts back.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what happened when `x = 1.002341` for examples. Base on your limited cases you can use this:

```
func myRound (var number : Double) -> Double {
    if number == 0 {
        return number
    }

    let integerPart = floor(number)
    var base = 1.0

    number -= integerPart
    while abs(number) < 1 {
        number *= 10.0
        base *= 10.0
    }

    return integerPart + round(number) / base
}
```