# Javascript - Most efficient way to round off float to nearest non-zero number

Tags: javascript, algorithm, floating-point, rounding, logarithm

I want to round off a float in Javascript, with (at least) 2 significant figures.

For example, with following desired results:

```
roundOff(0.000000001124)  // 0.0000000011 or 1.1e-9 (both acceptable)
roundOff(1.423421)  // 1.42
roundOff(0.00053245)  // 0.00053
roundOff(422.243224)  // 422.24
roundOff(422.0000000123)  // 422.00
```

I know I can use logarithm and round to do something similar as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32194113/1167918), but it rounds off even larger numbers, like `-123.0 -> -100`.

Any clever Javascript based solution?

Comment: Your question is unclear. How many significant figures do you need? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a function that returns two significant figures for numbers with an absolute value less than 1, or two decimal places for numbers with an absolute value greater than 1.

I still don't understand why you think `0.000000001124` should be rounded to `0.0000000012`. Did you mean to write `0.0000000011` instead?

If so, this function should do what you want:

```
function roundOff(n) {
  return parseFloat(n.toExponential(Math.max(1,2+Math.log10(Math.abs(n)))));
}
```

#### Examples:

```
var a = new Array(0.000000001124, 1.423421, 0.00053245, 422.243224,
                  422.0000000123, 123, -123);
for (i=0; i<7; i++) console.log(roundOff(a[i]));
```

**Output:**

```
1.1e-9
1.42
0.00053
422.24
422
123
-123
```

Comment: sorry for that 12 and 11 confusion. I've fixed it in original question.  trying your approach now.

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following function rounds off a given number as soon as 2 significant figures after the '.' appear. It performs validation of input and rounds 2nd significant figure depending on the value of the third.

```js
function roundOff(number) {
  var temp = "" + number,
      counterTwoFigures = 0,
      roundedNumber = '',
      startingIndex = temp.indexOf('.'),
      maxDecimalsAllowance = 20,
      multiplier = 100,
      minimumThreshold = 1;


  if(number * multiplier < minimumThreshold) {
    temp = parseFloat(temp).toFixed(maxDecimalsAllowance);
  }

  if(isNaN(number)){
    return undefined;
  }
  
  if(startingIndex === -1) {
    return number;
  }

  roundedNumber = temp.substring(0, startingIndex);

  for(var i = startingIndex, len = temp.length; i < len; i++){

    if((parseFloat(temp[i]) > 0)) {
      counterTwoFigures++;
    }

    if(counterTwoFigures > 2){
      if(temp[i] >= 5) {
        var updateNumber = "" + (parseFloat(roundedNumber[roundedNumber.length-1]) + 1);
        var positionToUpdate = roundedNumber.length-2;
        var initialString = roundedNumber.substr(0, roundedNumber.length - 1);
        roundedNumber = initialString + updateNumber;
        break;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }

    roundedNumber += temp[i];
  }
  
  return parseFloat(roundedNumber);
}

var a = new Array(0.000000001124, 1.423421, 0.00053245, 422.243224,
              422.0000000123, 123, -123, 0.687);
for (i=0; i<a.length; i++) console.log('Input: ' + a[i] + ', Output: ' + roundOff(a[i]));
```

Comment: `roundOff(0.000000001124) == 1.12` — that can't be right, surely?

Comment: The error was due to the fact that the number 0.000000001124 was being automatically converted to scientific notation. Since I'm converting it to a string, the algorithm was assuming 1.12e-9 was to be converted to 1.12 (after two significant figures, as it was requested).

I've added a verification and applied toFixed to numbers higher than 0.01 and lower than 1e-20 (which is the lower bound to apply .toFixed()).

Comment: OK, that's better. But shouldn't `roundOff(6.789)` be `6.79`? Your function returns `6.78`.

Comment: I've updated the solution with a replacement of the 2nd significant figure depending on the value of the 3rd figure: if the value is higher than 5, the 2nd figure is incremented by one.

Comment: Sorry to be such a nuisance, but `roundOff(0.1001) == 0.10`, surely? Your function returns `0.1001`.

Comment: No problem at all. You're helping me to sharp my coding skills. :)
I haven't thought about the case in which there's one significant figure followed by many zeros and finally with another significant figure. I agree that it should round to 0.1. I'll make the appropriate changes :)