# Results to two decimals using ST_Area

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have performed ST_Area on a shapefile but the resulting numbers are VERY long. Need to reduce them to two decimals. This is the code so far:

```
SELECT mtn_name, ST_Area(geom) / 1000000 AS km2 FROM mountain ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

This is what I get:

```
             mtn_name                                  KM2
        character varying                        double precision
1   Monte del Pueblo de Jerez del Marquesado    6.9435657067528e-9
2   Monte de La Peza                            6.113288075418532e-9
```

I tried ROUND() but it brings KM to 0.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is not simply possible to round a decimal value (Decimal Precision problem) you will not get a `double` value which is exactly `6.94e-9`. It would be something like `6.9400000001e-9` after rounding.

You can do:

[demos:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ad90985cbbae942332229fbed8bfd711)

1. If the exponent is always the same (in your example it is always `e-9`) you can round with a fixed value. With `double` values, this results in the problem described above.

   ```
   SELECT
       round(area * 10e8 * 100) / 100 / 10e8
   FROM area_result
   ```
2. To avoid these precision problems, you can use `numeric` type

   ```
   SELECT
       round(area * 10e8 * 100)::numeric / 100 / 10e8
   FROM area_result
   ```

If you have different exponents, you have to calculate the multiplicator first. According to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32194113/3984221) you can do:

3. For `double` output

   ```
   SELECT
       round(area / mul * 100) * mul / 100
   FROM (
       SELECT
           area,
           pow(10, floor(log10(area))) as mul
       FROM area_result
   ) s
   ```
4. For `numeric` output

   ```
   SELECT
       round((area / mul) * 100)::numeric * mul / 100
   FROM (
       SELECT
           area,
           pow(10, floor(log10(area)))::numeric as mul
       FROM area_result
   ) s
   ```

However, your exponential result is just a view of the values. This can vary from database tool to database tool. Internally they are not stored as the view. So, if you fetch these values, you will, in fact, get a value like `0.00000000694` and not `6.94e-9`, which is just a textual representation.

5. If you want to ensure to get exactly this textual representation, you can use number formatting `to_char()` for this, which, of course, returns a type `text`, not a number anymore:

   ```
   SELECT
       to_char(area, '9.99EEEE')
   FROM area_result
   ```

Comment: That worked! I used the last point #5 as I only need to observe results. Many thanks :)